# Swap text file columns and create new file

Tags: regex, bash, text-files, multiple-columns, swap

I have hundreds of large text files, `fileAn` and `fileBn`, in two folders `A` and `B`, from which I would like to swap the first six columns of each file. I would then save the new files `fileCn` and `fileDn` in folders `C` and `D`. There is an equal number of  files in `A` and `B` and file lengths are identical.

How can achieve this using bash or regex?

Here is a snippet of `fileA1`:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59841,0.327,3.275,1.89275,32.048,8,32,11.61
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.10",59842,0.086,3.56975,2.20325,32.10205,9,32,11.57
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.20",59843,0.26575,3.343,1.8285,32.06717,10,32,11.57
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.30",59844,-0.1915,3.28175,1.793,32.12122,11,32,11.57
```

`fileB1`:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59841,2.48975,2.8535,-0.6575,32.13168,9
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.10",59842,2.38975,3.10525,-0.62025,32.21362,10
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.20",59843,2.224,3.09825,-0.43375,32.19968,11
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.30",59844,2.102,3.029,-0.51825,32.21539,12
```

New file `fileC1`, first six columns `fileB1` replaced by first six columns from `fileA1`:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59841,0.327,3.275,1.89275,32.048,9
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.10",59842,0.086,3.56975,2.20325,32.10205,10
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.20",59843,0.26575,3.343,1.8285,32.06717,11
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.30",59844,-0.1915,3.28175,1.793,32.12122,12
```

New file `fileD1`, first six columns `fileA1` replaced by first six columns from `fileB1`:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59841,2.48975,2.8535,-0.6575,32.13168,8,32,11.61
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.10",59842,2.38975,3.10525,-0.62025,32.21362,9,32,11.57
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.20",59843,2.224,3.09825,-0.43375,32.19968,10,32,11.57
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.30",59844,2.102,3.029,-0.51825,32.21539,11,32,11.57
```

I had a look at the `paste` command but could not find a way to make this a batch process.

Comment: Did you also try to use `cut`?

Comment: only `paste -d, <(cut fileA1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileB1 -d, -f7) > fileC1` and `paste -d, <(cut fileB1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileA1 -d, -f7-9) > fileD1`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Thanks. I tested this on one file and it worked. I have been trying to apply this recursively for a large number of files using    *fileA1=find /path/to/folderA -name '*.csv'* and file *fileB1=find /path/to/folderB -name '*.csv'* but I get a syntax error when I apply this to the *paste* command.

Comment: @Buzz You should post another question

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. OK. If you put your first comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste` and `cut` for swapping columns in two files,

```
paste -d, <(cut fileA1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileB1 -d, -f7) > fileC1
paste -d, <(cut fileB1 -d, -f1-6) <(cut fileA1 -d, -f7-9) > fileD1
```